# How to get the summary band after last page footer band?

Tags: jasper-reports

In my jasper report the summary band comes between last page footer and detail band. I want to print the summary band at the last page of the report i.e after last page footer band. what should I do to get the summary band content after the last page footer band content.

Answer (score 1):

This is your magic setting on the `jasperReport` tag

```
isSummaryNewPage="true"
```

And make sure that you do **not** have `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"`

**Example**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
```

**EDIT:**

If you need page number also on this page, just add it to the summary band also

Answer (score 0):

Set `isSummaryNewPage="true"` in

if your are using iReport select report properties - Summary on a new page check box.
[ireport properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QXYh.png)

Comment: thanks for the comments. Im  using jaspersoft studio 6.1 . I also want to have page number displayed on summary band. if i untick  summary band header and footer  check box. it will not display page number in the summary section.